# Laravel controller validation of request with nested parameters

Tags: laravel, validation

I am trying to validate in my controller a request of nested parameters but I can't get it working. I did find a few resources online and tried different things with no success.
This is the script that sends the data to the controller:

```
var fieldsValuePair = {
    type: this.history.type
};

axios.get('/app/admin/cms/clients/processActivity', {
   params: {
      fieldsValuePair: fieldsValuePair,
      hid: this.history.hid
   }
})
.then((response) => {})
.catch(error => {
     this.errors = [];
     this.errors = error.response.data;
     console.log(this.errors);
});
```

This is my validation in my controller:

```
$this->validate($request, ['type' => 'required'] , ['activity-type.required']);
```

I want to say that if i add: `type: this.history.type` in my axios request just after `hid: this.history.hid` then the validation works correctly.
What I want to achieve is to have the `type: this.history.type` in the `fieldsValuePair` object and have this validate correctly in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution but not sure if this would be the best one. At least it's working for me.

```
$rulesArray = [];
    $fieldsValuePairArray = json_decode($request['fieldsValuePair'], true);
    foreach ($fieldsValuePairArray as $key => $value) {
        if($value == '')
            $rulesArray[$key] = 'required';
    }

    $this->validate($request, $rulesArray , ['activity-type.required']);
```